# get the count of a specific categorical variable in a data frame

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have the following Data frame

```
cars <- c("Toyota","Nissan","BMW","Nissan","Ford","Toyota","Nissan")
price <- c(21000, 23400, 26800,21000, 23400, 26800,21000)
salesDF <- data.frame(cars, price)
```

I want to get the count or the number of times "Nissan" has appeared  in the column `cars` and store it in a valueBox in Shiny. How can I get that specific count? In this case, how can I get the value `3` based on the number of times "Nissan" has appeared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, here are couple of them :

```
var = 'Nissan'
#1.
value <- sum(salesDF$cars == var)
value
#[1] 3

#2.
value <- nrow(subset(salesDF, cars == var))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`table`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/table) to get all counts, and [`subset`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/subset) to get the desired count:

```
counts <- as.data.frame(table(salesDF$cars))

print(counts)
##     Var1 Freq
## 1    BMW    1
## 2   Ford    1
## 3 Nissan    3
## 4 Toyota    2

print(subset(counts, Var1 == 'Nissan', select = -Var1))
##   Freq
## 3    3
```